# Django forms to one line

Tags: python, django, forms, authentication

I want to add {{ form.as_p }} which contains Username field and Password field in one line, NOT username above password.

like this: `Username: __________   Password: ___________`

Not like this:

```
Username: __________
Password: __________
```

I am using django's original OOB login authentication and I would like to ask how can I change the form.

I can provide code if you may ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `{{ form.as_table }}` in your template, then your desired apperance will be achived.

If you need another appearance take look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the form's fields doing

```
form.field_name
```

for example:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">{{form.username}}</div>
<div class="col-md-6">{{form.password}}</div>
<div>
```

see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options)

**EDIT**

Note that

```
row
```

and

```
col-md-6
```

are bootstrap classes

Comment: You forgot to mention that, for such solution @chazefate also need to  know what you mean by `class="row"` and `class="col-md-6"`.